# IE11 not loading big images. says script 14: not enough storage available to complete this operation

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, fileapi

I am developing a website where user will select images from their computer and a preview of images will be shown to them before any data is sent to server. I used File API for this and I am storing base64 data of images in an javascript array for sending to server. However, if I upload very big images say of size 15MB then after reading 4 images sometimes the next image isn't getting loaded. The debugger shows "script 14: not enough storage available to complete this operation". But this is working fine on other browsers. I am pulling my hair over this for a week now. Is their any restriction on the storage IE allocates to each website?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/10/wininet-internet-explorer-file-download-and-upload-maximum-size-limits.aspx

Comment: @adeneo the blog shows that maximum upload limit is 4GB but I am noway near that. It is failing even on 60MB.

Comment: @Laxmi did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

check how you create image object.
I had the same issue when i create the image using

```
var image = new Image()
```

this fail in IE for large image.

Found the [this](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/how-to-develop-a-html5-image-uploader/) link change the code as below. and image upload work for larger image.

here is the trick

```
 var img = document.createElement("img");
 img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
```